# Certbot failed to authenticate some domains не могу понять как это исправить

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, certbot

```
Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: standalone). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
Domain: procleaning.kg
Type:   connection
 Detail: (ip-adress): Fetching http://procleaning.kg/.well-known/acme-challenge/J5euZMCyWKJ-8VAaKoqgAJ-oMYrbhFkFCjb0xWmHYc8: Connection refused

Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the challenge files from the temporary standalone webserver started by Certbot on port 80. Ensure that the listed domains point to this machine and that it can accept inbound connections from the internet.

Some challenges have failed.
Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - ~/.pg/pg_data/app:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5434:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    env_file:
      - .env
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: djangowebsite
    environment:
      DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME: ${DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME}
      DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL: ${DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL}
      DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD: ${DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/app/static
      - media_volume:/app/media
    command: > 
      /bin/sh -c "
      /app/wait-for-it.sh db:5432 -- python manage.py makemigrations &&
      python manage.py migrate &&
      python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80"
  nginx:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      context: ./docker/nginx/
    container_name: app_nginx
    image: app_nginx
    volumes:
      - www-html:/var/www/html
      - /docker/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - etc-letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - static_volume:/app/static
      - media_volume:/app/media
    depends_on:
      - web
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - etc-letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - www-html:/var/www/html
    command: certonly --standalone --email aldiarm27@gmail.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email -d procleaning.kg


volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
  www-html:
  etc-letsencrypt:
```

nginx.conf:

```
upstream web {
    server web:80;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name procleaning.kg;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
            allow all;
            root /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /app/static_root/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /app/media/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name procleaning.kg;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    root /var/www/html;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/north.world-ithech.ru/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/north.world-ithech.ru/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass wp:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

git bash Ubuntu server:

```
root@procleaningkg:/home/ProCleaning# sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      477435/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      477309/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      477440/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      477314/docker-proxy
```

Comment: Точно такая же проблема, буду рад если кто-то поможет!